# Change form style/appearance to Node.js applications

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, forms

I would know how to change the window form style to an app built with node.js . I mean, once we finish our app and we packaged it with node.js, when we launch it we'll have the windows 7 ( if we use windows 7) form style, Windows 8 form style if we use windows 8, etc..

How can I change the form style?

How can I change the appearance of my application without the traditional form style of the OS we're using?